# CRD host for linux - "OAuth credentials are invalid"

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, remote-desktop, chromium

I was trying to build the chromium source for the chrome remote desktop host and chromoting web app in linux. I followed the instructions from [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ChromotingBuildInstructions) and [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/184niJVxEfBoYqOrL_BLIHR8PNTbvCnGcFy3Rwb7NbPU/edit), and the build was successful.

But the problem is when I add the chromoting webapp as an extension, it starts, asks for authorization, but after that shows:

**`Error: invalid_client`**

Examining the request details, I got **`client_id=dummytoken`** and believe this is the problem. So my question is, why this is happening and how can I solve this?

Another problem is when I try to start the chrome remote desktop host process, it stops with the following message:

```
...
Launching host process
['/opt/google/chrome-remote-desktop/chrome-remote-desktop-host', '--host-config=-', '--audio-pipe-name=/home/diptap/.config/chrome-remote-desktop/pulseaudio#7e4d6b70aa/fifo_output', '--signal-parent']
wait() returned (6794,26112)
Host process terminated
Failure count for 'host' is now 1
OAuth credentials are invalid - exiting.
Cleanup.
Terminating Xvfb
....
```

**Why my credentials are invalid?** Are these two problems are related? I got them according to the steps mentioned in the links.

*This is first time I am building chromium or any chrome app, I may miss something obvious.*

Answer (score 1):

ok so I just figured this part out. Stuck at the next stage. I shall help you move forward.

I assume you compiled the chromoting webapp yourself. the credentials from the google cloud console dont seem to stick when you build it. I had to manually add it later.

Go to the folder where the app is located and modify plugin_settings.js as follows

```
remoting.Settings.prototype.OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'YOUR CLIENT ID HERE'
remoting.Settings.prototype.OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'YOUR CLIENT SECRET HERE'
```

and now you should be able to get past that stage. Infact you will now be able to access remote machines. enabling remote access to this machine however is posing me a few small problems. let me know where you get to

Comment: Thanks @Roopak. I have figured out the problem and completed the build long ago. Thanks for your answer though..

Comment: had to answer for the community :) I found your question... had no answer, so thought I would put stuff here for the next person who finds it